# (mysql workbench)ERROR 1273 (HY000) at line 25: Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci' --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, collation

i an importing sql dump file in my database but getting this error

```
     11:29:12 Restoring E:\ews project\dumps\Dump20230525.sql
 Running: mysql.exe --defaults-file="C:\Users\INP\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpz8kesn1f.cnf"  - 
 -protocol=tcp --host=164.164.32.6 --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 
 --comments --database=practice  < "E:\\ews project\\dumps\\Dump20230525.sql"
 ERROR 1273 (HY000) at line 25: Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'

 Operation failed with exitcode 1
 11:29:14 Import of E:\ews project\dumps\Dump20230525.sql has finished with 1 errors
```

i have also tried as per this link that change the COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci; from COLLATE=utf8mb4_ai_ci;

[ERROR 1273 (HY000) at line 1520: Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58327888/error-1273-hy000-at-line-1520-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-0900-ai-ci)

but still same error occuring.
these are the version of  MYSQL dump file and platform

### MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.33, for Linux (x86_64)

-- Host: 127.0.0.1    Database: practice

---

-- Server version   8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2

these are the version of  MYSQL importing mysql workwench and platform

### MySQL workwench 8.0.03  Distrib 8.0.33, for windows (x86_64)

-- Host: 127.0.0.1    Database: practice

---

-- Server version   8.0.3-windows 11

Comment: What exactly is the version of the MySQL server you import to, and what was the version of the MySQL server where you created the dump? The latter should be included in the header of your `Dump20230525.sql` file.

Comment: Also, what **exactly** have you tried? What has changed as you performed the changes in your attempts? Please edit your question to add these details; do not add them as a comment.

Comment: The fix you point to would have involved editing the `Dump20230525.sql` file. Is that what you did?

Comment: .03 is for workbench, not server.  Server 8.0.3 is pre-release; upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MYSQL server workbench version mismatch . so uninstall workbench and install again. and configure connection then import dump file